# Node Js Module Layering

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

If you had a server js like so:

```
var app = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    news = require('./server/api/news'),
    db = require('mongoose');

/* app config..... */
app.get('/api/news', news.list);


var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log("Server running");
});
```

And I wanted to create an API to handle adding news items to the database:

```
var db = require('mongoose');

/*** Public Interfaces ***/
function list(req, res) {
    var offset = ~~req.query.offset || 0,
        limit = ~~req.query.limit || 25;

    db.News.find(function (err, newsItems) {
        res.json(newsItems.slice(offset*limit, offset*limit + limit));
    });   
}

exports.list = list;
```

This API would exist in its own file, how do I use the instance of the `db` created in the `server.js` inside the new module.

Or do you create and open a new connection each time you query the database?

Thanks

Comment: How are you using `list`? You can wrap an outer function around the `list` function and pass arguments, but it depends on how the `list` method is required as you'd have to change it to `require('list')(db);` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do it more like this

the server :

```
var express = require('express'),
    app     = express(),
    http    = require('http'),
    db      = require('mongoose'),
    news    = require('./server/api/news')(db); // you can pass anything as args

app.get('/api/news', news.list);
/* add routes here, or use a file for the routes */
// app.get('/api/morenews', news.more_news); .... etc

http.createServer(app).listen(8000);
```

and in the `../news/index.js` file or whatever you're using, I'd use a literal, but you can always use exports to pass back each method as well

```
module.exports = function(db) {
    /* now db is always accessible within this scope */
    return {
        list : function (req, res) {
            var offset = ~~req.query.offset || 0,
                limit = ~~req.query.limit || 25;

            db.News.find(function (err, newsItems) {
                res.json(newsItems.slice(offset*limit, offset*limit + limit));
            });
        }, // now you can easily add more properties
        more_news : function(req, res) {
            res.end('Hello kitty');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that is sick, do you just start up the db connect, when the server starts up?!

Comment: Yes, if you wanted you could have just one database connection and use it across the application by passing it around. I do this for all sorts of stuff, sometimes I need access to `app` in a routes file etc. so I just pass the `app` variable to the routes this way, and I like literal objects, so use those a lot, never liked the node way of multiple `exports.somevalue` etc. It's just javascript, so you can do pretty much whatever you like, as long as it's valid javascript and you don't create memory issues or other problems.

Comment: sounds like a good way, just for clarity's sake, if i were to create a module, if I put all the variables on the exports then does that mean as soon as the instance is created I can access those variables where ever the module is injected?

Comment: using mongoose, where do the models need to get defined, and where can they be used? if they were attached to the instance of `db` before it was injected into this api will the api be able to use it?

Comment: You can just try stuff out, in javascript it usually either works or not, even if some strange patterns can lead to unexpected things. If you attach something to the db object as a new property, yes, it can be accessed in the files where db is passed as an argument as well.

Comment: I'm working on something now where I threw everything out the window and went with another pattern completely, and did this -> http://jsfiddle.net/z2CrA/, and it works great.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you're setting things up synchronously in the `init()`, so do you create the db instance, then on the next serial function, create the models and schemas?

Comment: I'm using clusters, so I decided to try using an object where all the stuff I need are properties, that way it's easier to pass around, and yes, I initialize everything, connect to the DB, then in the db.build function I build everything, check if the database is prefilled with whatever should be there etc. and then I can just pass the DB to the routes and use it there, without having to do it all over again somewhere else, I have one single place where all the database stuff is, one place with all the routes etc. makes it easier to keep track of everything.